# Neo4j won't start on arch linux - "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log"

Tags: java, neo4j, slf4j, archlinux

I'm trying to install neo4j on a arch linux machine, but I have run into trouble. This is the error message I get: http://pastie.org/8646079.

I have tried following the installation instructions for linux in the manual and I have tried to install the package from AUR (non-official arch linux packages), but both give the same error.

I think it might be related to conflicting versions of slf4j, but I'm not really sure, so here's all the hits I get when searching for *slf4j* in my filesystem: http://pastie.org/8646086

If anybody knows what is wrong and how to fix it, I would be really happy!

**Edit:** Fixed this. Uninstalled jdk, removed /opt/java and reinstalled, which fixed it. It seems that a copy of slf4j had been installed to /opt/java but not removed properly.

Comment: SLF4J 1.7.5 is required for LocationAwareLogger. it is obvious that confliction is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can start neo4j by adding -verbose=class to the startup script?

To see which classes are loaded from where? It should then be listed in `/path/to/neo4j/log/console.log`

The Neo4j installation should only load files from `/path/to/neo4j/lib` and `/path/to/neo4j/system/lib`

If slf4j is loaded from somewhere else we have to figure out how it gets on the classpath for Neo4j.

Comment: This is the output with -verbose:class: http://pastie.org/8650379 and this is the classpath provided to the start command: http://pastie.org/8650389

Comment: Fixed this. Uninstalled jdk, removed /opt/java and reinstalled, which fixed it. It seems that a copy of slf4j had been installed to /opt/java but not removed properly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!